# create prefix lists through data in json file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create separate prefix lists using below json file with each prefix list should contain cidr values in the list. Please help on this

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Cidr": "192.168.1.0/32",
      "Description": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Cidr": "192.168.1.10/32",
      "Description": "Test1"
    }
  ],
  "Rules1": [
    {
      "Cidr": "192.168.2.0/32",
      "Description": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Cidr": "192.168.2.10/32",
      "Description": "Test1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Terraform code

```
resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "pl-Rules" {
  name           = "pl-Rules"
  address_family = "IPv4"
  max_entries    = 7
}

resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "pl-Rules1" {
  name           = "pl-Rules1"
  address_family = "IPv4"
  max_entries    = 7
}

resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list_entry" "entry" {

  cidr           = <Rules.cidr>
  description    = <Rules.description>
  prefix_list_id = aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.pl-Rules.id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read in the json file and then you need to build a suitable map to hold the configuration.

You can use (assuming your file is called `config.json`):

```
locals {
  config      = jsondecode(file("config.json"))
  rules_names = keys(local.config)
  rules_config = tomap(merge([
    for rule, v in local.config : {
      for i, rule_config in v : "${rule}_${i}" => {
        rule_name   = rule
        cidr        = rule_config.Cidr
        description = rule_config.Description
      }
    }
  ]...))
}

resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "pl-Rules" {
  for_each       = { for idx, rule_names in local.rules_names : rule_names => idx }
  name           = "pl-${each.key}"
  address_family = "IPv4"
  max_entries    = 7
}

resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list_entry" "entry" {
  for_each       = local.rules_config
  cidr           = each.value.cidr
  description    = each.value.description
  prefix_list_id = aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.pl-Rules["${each.value.rule_name}"].id
}
```

Comment: yes @Paolo it worked perfectly, thank you. I'm trying to understand the code, would be great.

Comment: Did not understand why did you use expanding function arguments in the locals block